# Convert SVN repository to git

Tags: svn, git, perl

```
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.8.9 (r1591380)

$ git --version
git version 1.7.1

$ git svn clone http://host/path/to/project/
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/to/project/.git/
Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so' for module SVN::_Core: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so: undefined symbol: svn_swig_pl_thunk_gnome_keyring_unlock_prompt at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 200.
 at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/SVN/Base.pm line 59
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/SVN/Core.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 41.
```

If I use a more recent git:

```
$ /opt/git/bin/git --version
git version 2.7.0.GIT
```

I get:

```
Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so' for module SVN::_Core: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so: undefined symbol: svn_swig_pl_thunk_gnome_keyring_unlock_prompt at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 200.
 at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/SVN/Base.pm line 59
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/SVN/Core.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/git/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/git/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/git/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 32.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/git/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 32.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/git/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 21.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have missed subversion-perl package

```
# yum provides "*/_Core.so"
subversion-perl-1.6.11-15.el6_7.x86_64 : Perl bindings to the Subversion libraries
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so
```

I have noticed that path /usr/lib64/.../_Core/_Core.so is specific for subversion 1.6.x, at the same time with version 1.8.x it would be /usr/local/lib64/.../_Core/_Core.so. At least for wandisco packages

**SUBVERSION 1.8.x**

```
# rpm -qa | grep subversion
subversion-1.8.15-1.x86_64
subversion-tools-1.8.15-1.x86_64
subversion-perl-1.8.15-1.x86_64

# rpm -qf /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so
subversion-perl-1.8.15-1.x86_64

# strings /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so | grep svn_swig_pl_thunk_gnome_keyring_unlock_prompt
svn_swig_pl_thunk_gnome_keyring_unlock_prompt
```

**SUBVERSION 1.6.x**

```
# rpm -qa | grep subversion
subversion-perl-1.6.23-4.x86_64
subversion-1.6.23-4.x86_64
subversion-tools-1.6.23-4.x86_64

# rpm -ql subversion-perl | grep _Core.so
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so

# strings /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so | grep svn_swig_pl_thunk_gnome_keyring_unlock_prompt
```

As for me, I prefer [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) utility written in ruby. It's more comfortable

Comment: Thank you @ALex_hha, but I get:  `Package subversion-perl-1.6.11-15.el6_7.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

Comment: Strange, works for me. But you have wrote that you have svn version 1.8.9. Do you mix subversion 1.8.9 and subversion-perl 1.6.11 packages from different version?

Answer (score -1):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/perl5/Alien/SVN
```

Comment: This needs explanation